# pandas.read_html converting only specific columns to float

Tags: python, pandas, type-conversion

I am trying to create a program that read a table in a site and convert only part of a table columns to float.

This site tables are like this below:

```
Account   Responsible     Grade
1.0.0     João Da Silva   3,5
1.1.0     Antônio Pereira 2,5
1.2.0     Maria do Céu    4,5
1.2.1     Joana Antunes   5,0
```

to do this, I used BeautifulSoup and pandas.read_html as below

```
import BeautifulSoup as bs
import pandas as pd
############################################################
# This part of the code was voided to simplify my question #
############################################################
soup = bs(page_source,'html.parser')
table = soup.find('table',{'id': 'table_id'})
data = pd.read_html(str(table), encoding = 'utf-8', decimal=",", thousands='.')[0]
```

when I do this, the table is converted as I want except to the "Account" column and the returned pandas data frame is like below:

```
Index   1       2               3
0       Account Responsible     Grade
1       100     João Da Silva   3.5
2       110     Antônio Pereira 2.5
3       120     Maria do Céu    4.5
4       121     Joana Antunes   5.0
```

My idea is to keep "Account" column values as it was in original table to avoid any miss-conversion and convert  other tables values as it should be (for this example, it should be [str,str,float]).

```
Index   1         2               3
0       Account   Responsible     Grade
1       1.0.0     João Da Silva   3.5
2       1.1.0     Antônio Pereira 2.5
3       1.2.0     Maria do Céu    4.5
4       1.2.1     Joana Antunes   5.0
```

Is there any possible way to perform this kind o conversion?

Thanks for all possible support from now and best regards.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to set the converter for that column.

```
data = pd.read_html(str(table), encoding = 'utf-8', decimal=",", thousands='.', converters={'Account': str})[0]
```

Comment: I tried to set the converter as you proposed, but it didn't work. The Account column is still been translated to integer.

Comment: what is the dtype of the dataframe. what does `print(data.dtypes)` show?

Comment: It is returning: "object" to Account column, "object" to Responsible column and "float 64" to Grade.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/10534#issuecomment-639522524) helps:

```
data = pd.read_html(str(table), encoding = 'utf-8', thousands="ª", decimal="ª")[0]
data['Grade'] = data['Grade'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace(',', '.')))
```

or [this](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/25218#issuecomment-462029019):

```
data = pd.read_html(str(table), encoding = 'utf-8', thousands=None)[0]
data['Grade'] = data['Grade'].apply(lambda x: float(x.replace(',', '.')))
```

Comment: My solution was something like what you did. But I was looking for some more "pandemic solution", using pandas dataframe configuration.